# Excel - INDEX(MATCH) or similar to return an array

Tags: excel

Supposing the following catalogue of prices:

```
SHEET 1

      A           B
    1 APPLES      1000
    2 FISH        2000
    3 BUTTONS     3000
    4 MINCEPIES   4343
    5 HAMMERS     2343
```

I would like to return an array of values for items of an arbitrary length:

```
SHEET 2

      A
    1 HAMMERS
    2 FISH
    3 BUTTONS
    4 MINCEPIES
    5 APPLES
    6 FISH
```

I need a formula which will return an array of values of column B on Sheet 1 based on the text of column A of Sheet 2 ... so:
2343;2000;3000;4343;1000;2000

I want to use the array as a component for use in a SUMPRODUCT formula. The closest I have come so far is:

`{=INDEX(Sheet1!B1:B5,MATCH(Sheet2!A1,Sheet1!A1:A5,0),0)}`

... however this does not return an array, it just matches the value which corresponds to the top most MATCH column.

Thanks

Comment: SUMIF(), VLOOKUP(), INDEX(MATCH())... the list goes on. Pick one.

Comment: Can you try answering the question? What formula could I use to return an array? @Jeeped

Comment: @Jeeped do you appreciate that I'm attempting to return an **array** of values?

Comment: Yes, and additionally I can a) appreciate that you have demonstrated no original effort into resolving your problem and b) have not adequately described what you want to do with the array once you achieve it. With regards to the latter, the method of achieving the array would be very different depending on whether it was intended to be the *RefersTo:* of a named range, the *Source:* of a data validation list or simply an array formula filling a predetermined range of cells.

Comment: I'm wanting to use the array as a product for use in a SUMPRODUCT formula. I thought it might be best to keep the question simple hence the brevity. The closest I have come so far is: {=INDEX(Sheet1!B1:B5,MATCH(Sheet2!A1,Sheet1!A1:A5,0),0)} - however this does not return an array, it just matches the value which corresponds to the top most MATCH column. Your continued input appreciated.

Comment: `{=INDEX(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$5, MATCH(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$6, Sheet1!$A$1:$A$5, 0))}` is one array formula that fits. This is demonstrated by selected 6 cells (e.g. D2:D7), putting in that formula and hitting CSE. You get the numbers in the correct order. How you are going to get that to fit into your imaginary SUMPRODUCT is anyone's guess as you've decided to keep that a secret.

Comment: This isn't going well is it. I'll start a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the many approaches...

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet1!$B$2:$C$6,2,FALSE)
```

where `B2` is the value you want to "look up", `Sheet1!$B$2:$C$6` is the "array" in your first sheet that includes both (names and values), `2` is for returning the value from the second column, `FALSE`is in order to get the exact match.

[More info](http://www.excelfunctions.net/Excel-Vlookup-Tutorial.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am looking to return an array of the data - something similar to: =INDEX(Sheet1!B1:B5,MATCH(Sheet2!A1,Sheet1!A1:A5,0),0) - I don't just want 1 value, I want an array of values: 2343;2000;3000;4343;1000;2000

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... once you get all the individual values in a column, say the results are individually from C2 to C7, you can select the next 6 cells from D2 to D7, and type =C2:C7 and hit CSE (Ctrl-Shift-Enter), that will generate your array. Check: http://i.imgur.com/KMao1Mm.png

Comment: I'm marking your answer as correct, as you have been helpful - but to be honest I have reposted the question providing better information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28894474/sumproduct-index-match - thank you!