# SUMPRODUCT INDEX MATCH

Tags: excel

With the following data:

```
    A       B
1   CUMULATIVE PERCENTAGE OF ITEMS PRODUCED PER MONTH ("COMPLETION_TABLE")
2   Type     Month 1   Month 2
3   KITTENS  0         10
4   FISH     0         20
5   BANANAS  2         5
6   APPLES   0         0
7   PEARS    0         5
8   KITTENS  0         5
9           
10          
11  PRICES TABLE ("PRICES_TABLE")
12  Type     Value  
13  APPLES   1000   
14  BANANAS  5000   
15  PEARS    3000   
16  FISH     4000   
17  KITTENS  2000
```

I'm attempting to use the SUMPRODUCT function to calculate the percentage change in each month and use that value as a multiple of the prices table to provide a total price per month across all types that have been produced.

I can calculate the movement as:

`=SUMPRODUCT((COMPLETION_TABLE[Month 2]-COMPLETION_TABLE[Month 1]))`

... but I then need to calculate the portion of the individual movement values against the price for that type and sum the resulting products together. I have been using various INDEX / MATCH combinations without much luck.

As an example: BANANAS which should `=(5-2)*5000`.

Written as expanded arrays I would like to do

```
({10;20;5;0;5;5}-{0;0;2;0;0;0})*{2000;4000;5000;1000;3000;2000}.
```

Comment: could you give an example of what the result would be like for `13 APPLES 1000`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use of `SUMPRODUCT` implies you want a single figure result. You can use `SUMIF` as a "pseudo lookup" within `SUMPRODUCT` to get the prices, e.g.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(C3:C8-B3:B8,SUMIF(A13:A17,A3:A8,B13:B17))
```

That would get you a result of 140,000 for your example

Answer (score 3):

From your question I understand the result you want is an array. This is what you get with this formula:

```
=INDEX($B$13:$B$17,MATCH($A3:$A8,$A$13:$A$17,0))*($C3:$C8-$B3:$B8)
```

entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I am sure there is something simpler. I am assuming that the Type in the Price Table are unique:

`{=(SUM((A13=$A$3:$A$8)*$C$3:$C$8)-SUM((A13=$A$3:$A$8)*$B$3:$B$8))*SUM((A13=$A$13:$A$17)*$B$13:$B$17)`